# How to increase event loop capacity in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, capacity

I know that Node.js uses a single-thread and an event loop to process requests only processing one at a time (which is non-blocking). But i am unable to determine **Event loop capacity** to run 100k request per second.

Here i want to capacity planning for nodejs server to handle the **100k request per second**.

Please let me know how can i determine the capacity of event loop to increase capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single instance of Node.js runs in a **single thread**. To take advantage of multi-core systems the user will sometimes want to **launch a cluster of Node.js processes** to handle the load.

More info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and [here](http://stackabuse.com/setting-up-a-node-js-cluster/)

For the reference check following code for simple implementation of cluster in node.js

```
var cluster = require('cluster');  
var express = require('express');  
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        // Create a worker
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    // Workers share the TCP connection in this server
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    // All workers use this port
    app.listen(8080);
}
```

[Cluster](http://learnboost.github.io/cluster/) is an extensible multi-core server manager for node.js for more source check [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster).

Comment: It would be better if you put a working code example rather than just posting links.

Comment: @Eugen Dimboiu, You are right. but here i want to know that one event loop's capacity. if there is any tool to determine single event loop capacity or any other way, so that i can accordingly increase no of cpus.

Comment: As far as I know there is no specific tool for your need, but you can use any load testing tool to stress test your app. I think you'll need to design your app so it can scale horizontally with ease - 100k requests/second is a lot.